# Next value by previous data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query that will query the next result by looking into data as how it previous was.

So my data is like

```
Train - Station   -  Time
158     Station1     11:10
158     Station1     11:11
158     Station1     11:12
158     Station1     11:13
158     Station1     11:14
158     Station2     11:25
158     Station2     11:26
158     Station2     11:27
158     Station3     11:41
158     Station3     11:42
158     Station3     11:43
158     Station3     11:44
158     Station3     11:45
158     Station4     11:50
158     Station4     11:51
158     Station4     11:52
158     Station4     11:53
```

So lets say im at "Station3"

I am using the following query to find out what previous Station is:

```
SELECT * FROM Train 
WHERE Train = '158' AND Station NOT LIKE 'Station3' 
ORDER BY Time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I want to query what the next Station is, but i cant really figure out to make that query. Any tips?

**Edit:**
Ok, lets say that my table have more information, about previous train runs, and it is from that i want to check what the next station will be.
    Train - Station   -  Time
    158     Station1     10:10
    158     Station1     10:11
    158     Station1     10:12
    158     Station1     10:13
    158     Station1     10:14
    158     Station2     10:25
    158     Station2     10:26
    158     Station2     10:27
    158     Station3     10:41
    158     Station3     10:42
    158     Station3     10:43
    158     Station3     10:44
    158     Station3     10:45
    158     Station4     10:50
    158     Station4     10:51
    158     Station4     10:52
    158     Station4     10:53
    158     Station5     10:55
    158     Station5     10:56
    158     Station6     10:57
    158     Station6     10:58
    158     Station1     11:10
    158     Station1     11:11
    158     Station1     11:12
    158     Station1     11:13
    158     Station1     11:14
    158     Station2     11:25
    158     Station2     11:26
    158     Station2     11:27
    158     Station3     11:41
    158     Station3     11:42
    158     Station3     11:43
    158     Station3     11:44
    158     Station3     11:45
    158     Station4     11:50
    158     Station4     11:51
    158     Station4     11:52
    158     Station4     11:53
    159     Station1     11:10
    159     Station1     11:11
    159     Station1     11:12
    159     Station1     11:13
    159     Station1     11:14
    159     Station2     11:25
    159     Station2     11:26
    159     Station2     11:27
    159     Station3     11:41
    159     Station3     11:42
    159     Station3     11:43
    159     Station3     11:44
    159     Station3     11:45
    159     Station4     11:50
    158     Station4     11:51
    159     Station4     11:52
    159     Station4     11:53

So lets say im at the Train 158 Station4 Time 11:53, and i dont know what the next Station is, and i want to query it is Station5. How would i be doing that?

Comment: Your query will not give you the previous station reliably. With the data given, it would return Station4 11:53

Answer (score 2):

if you only need to know the next station you could use a subquery for max time for station3 and train 158

```
  select * from 
  my_table 
  where time > ( 
  select max(time) max_time
  from my_table 
  where Train = '158' AND Station = 'Station3' )
  and train = '158'
  order by time limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Other approach with out first finding the MAX(time) for station.

MySQL 8.0+ makes it really eazy with LEAD to get the next records data.

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Table1.Train
 , Table1.next_station AS station
 , Table1.next_station_time AS time
FROM ( 

   SELECT 
     *
     , LEAD(Station) OVER (PARTITION BY Train ORDER BY Time) AS next_station
     , LEAD(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Train ORDER BY Time) AS next_station_time
   FROM
    Table1
   WHERE
     Train = 158 
)
 AS Table1

WHERE
   Table1.station = 'station3'
 AND
   Table1.station <> Table1.next_station
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Ld7XznMEuzNdRC3dmysUt/1

In the older MySQL versions we need to be more creative because LEAD isn't supported. 
Best way to simulate LEAD is by using MySQL's user variables, and a shifting self LEFT JOIN 
Keep in mind MySQL user variables work in MySQL 5.1+

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   current_train AS train
 , next_station AS station
 , next_time AS time
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
      t1.Train AS current_train
    , t1.Station AS current_station
    , t1.Time AS `current_time`
    , t2.Train AS next_train
    , t2.Station AS next_station
    , t2.Time AS next_time
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      *
      , @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rownum
    FROM 
      Table1
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rownum1 := 0 ) AS i 
    WHERE
      Train = 158
    ORDER BY 
      Time ASC
  ) AS t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      *
      , @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum
    FROM 
      Table1
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rownum2 := 0 ) AS i   
    WHERE
      Train = 158 
    ORDER BY 
      Time ASC 
  ) AS t2
  ON   
   t1.rownum + 1 = t2.rownum
 ) 
 AS records
WHERE
   records.current_station = 'station3'
 AND
   records.current_station <> records.next_station
```

See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff23fc/38

Answer (score 0):

On a simpler way, using self `join` could help you achieve it.

Try this:

```
select t1.* from train t1 
right join train t2 on t1.train=t2.train
where t1.station != 'Station3' and t1.time>(t2.time)
and t2.station='Station3' limit 1 ;
```

Try changing the `station` value on both table `t1` and `t2` to your desired value which is `Station3` in this case.

Live SQL Fiddle demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d36cc3/2).